# Android activity not starting

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am starting a new activity from the first screen in my application, when someone presses a button.

For some reason, when I try to start StoryBoard, it appears that MainScreen is simply being reloaded.

The first activity in my app is called MainScreen. I am trying to start StoryBoard, am I doing it correctly?

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainScreen.this, StoryBoard.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("sportName", sportName);
        myIntent.putExtra("stories", storiesAsArray);
        myIntent.setClass(this, StoryBoard.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: Did you declare StoryBoard in the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: Yes, I have it declared:                                    <activity android:name=".StoryBoard"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
       </activity>

Comment: Your `setClass()` line is superfluous, as you already provided that info in the constructor.

Comment: It's still just 'restarting' MainScreen.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainScreen.this, StoryBoard.class);
myIntent.putExtra("sportName", sportName);
myIntent.putExtra("stories", storiesAsArray);
MainScreen.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: should I be calling finish() before, or after I do this?

Comment: I also have a Log print out in the onCreate() method on StoryBoard, and that is being called, so this is strange.

Comment: you want to finish MainScreen activity? You can add your activities in a arraylist<Activity>. After starting the activity storyboard, you can finish myarraylist.get(index).finish()..

Comment: I guess I don't have to finish the activity, the flow of the app just moves from MainScreen to StoryBoard. I can't figure out why the StoryBoard is not loading, but the Log statement in StoryBoards onCreate() is being shown, so I know that it is trying to create the new activity.

Comment: StoryBoard is started you say.okey, what is not loading?, you setcontenview, i dont understand the problem.

Comment: I'm saying that onCreate() is being called, because I see the print out in the log file,  but I don't see the activity on the screen.

Comment: Do you have the layout for StoryBoard?  Try setContentView(R.layout.blabla); after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); .

Comment: Yep. I have the layout specified as the 2nd line in onCreate():      after super.onCreate(icicle);          setContentView(R.layout.stories);

Comment: I think I figured out the problem. I removed some code in MainScreen using JSoup, and it suddenly started working. I've been having problems getting the JAR files to be included in the build for some reason. But the behavior of simply restarting MainScreen doesn't seem right

Comment: can you offer any help at all on how to get the JAR file I need to be included in the build. I kept getting a NoClassDefFoundError, but now the behavior is simply for it to just reload MainScreen

Comment: properties -->java build path -->libraries--> add jars?

Comment: I'm using NetBeans, I'm not seeing a build path